# Emacs: line numbers that respect line-wrapping

Tags: emacs

**Modes**: I'm using linum for line numbers, the package linum-relative for relative line numbers.  If it matters, I am also using visual-line-mode.  These are flexible.

Currently, a single line (i.e. text without a newline) is numbered as only one line, regardless of how many times it is wrapped.  I am wondering if there is a way to change the numbering to respect these wraps.  So, for example,

```
263   This is all in
      a single line
      without newlines
```

might become:

```
263   This is all in
264   a single line
265   without newlines
```

---

and, in relative mode:

```
0     This is all in
      a single line
      without newlines
```

might become:

```
-1    This is all in
0     a single line
1     without newlines
```

---

I really only want the change in relative mode, but would not mind if it spills over into absolute mode.

A toggled change that works on both would be most useful - that way, the user can specifically select when, or with which modes, to turn it off or on.

Comment: Can you clarify the objective?  I'm not sure I see the purpose of fake line numbers when commands like `forward-line` won't respect them.  Also, I would think 263a, b, c, etc. would be much less confusing when you wanted to use `goto-line`

Comment: Interactive commands like `next-line` have respected wrapped newlines for years; do you mean `goto-line`? The request starts to make sense when you consider the use case of relative line numbers. Imagine looking at a very long wrapped line. The current visual line is numbered 0, the next visual line 1, and so on. Interesting text at relative line 15 can be reached with `C-u 15 down`. This is something I cannot do now without using the mouse, or without repeatedly pressing the down arrow.

Comment: While I can understand your use-case w/relative numbering, if the objective is buffer navigation, I think there are better solutions than C-u # up/down.

Comment: I'm using relative line numbers with evil.  With relative, I can instantly see if I have to move, say, 15 down or up, then type `15j` or `k` (in reality, `15e` or `u` due to colemak, but I doubt that matters).  I'm experimenting with setting j/k to `previous-line`/`next-line` so that it does respect wrapped lines.  The problem (for which I made this question) is that the relative line numberings don't, so I have to eyeball the number of lines if it's wrapped text.

Answer (score 4):

If the goal is navigation, I suggest a similar solution via the popular `ace-jump-mode`.

If the goal is just persistent line numbering, you might consider `longlines-mode` instead of `visual-line-mode` (but I would avoid this, personally).

**ace-jump @ GitHub**

https://github.com/winterTTr/ace-jump-mode

**Demo:**

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3254819/AceJumpModeDemo/AceJumpDemo.htm

With it, you can jump to any line with as little as two keypresses.

In addition to lines, you can jump to the start of any word; there's also individual character-level jump precision.  If desired, it can be configured to restrict jumps to the current window/buffer, or across all windows in the current frame, and even multi-frames.

It doesn't, however, recognize wrapped lines as jump-able locations.  Again, you *might* consider `longlines-mode` as a fix for this if it is *really* important to you, but as I understand, it's considered hack'ish and deprecated in favor of `visual-line-mode`.  Though, with `longlines-mode`, the lines are renumbered exactly as you want in your first example.

I'm assuming the goal is navigation, and as such, I think you'll find with just a little practice that word-based jumping or even jumping via incremental search to be a superior solution.

### Update

Here's a simple solution to trick ace-jump to scan within N lines using emacs narrowing features; perhaps others can improve upon it.  You could also do something similar for word and line modes.

```lisp
(defun brian-ace-jump-to-char-within-N-lines (&optional n)
  (interactive "p")
  (let* ((N (or n 0))
     (query-char (read-char "Query Char:"))
     (start (save-excursion
          (forward-line (- N))
          (point)))
     (stop (save-excursion 
         (forward-line (1+ N))
         (point))))
    (unwind-protect
    (condition-case err 
        (progn
          (narrow-to-region start stop)
          (ace-jump-char-mode query-char))
      (error 
       (message (error-message-string err))))
      (widen))))
```

Comment: Is there a way to ace-jump-to-char-in-current-line or within-N-lines? (in order to reduce the number of matches hence hopefully number of keypresses).

Comment: @spacingissue AFAIK, it's not in ace-jump by default, but I updated the answer with one solution for this feature that uses narrowing and widening.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The only issue I can see is that it should be `(or n 0)` for the current line, making the `if` conditions actually unnecessary.